# Mongoose - why isn't subdocument working?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, model, subdocument

I'm making a polling app and I would like to save users who have voted on a poll based either on their user ID, IP address or MAC address.

I figured it would be straight forward by having a `voted: VotedSchema` attribute in my `Poll` model, but for some reason it's not working.

**Poll model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const OptionSchema = require('./Option');
const VotedSchema = require('./Voted');

const pollSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  options: [OptionSchema],
  dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  voted: VotedSchema
});

mongoose.model('polls', pollSchema);
```

**Voted subdoc:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const votedSchema = new Schema({
  userID: [String],
  IPaddress: [String],
  MACaddress: [String]
});

module.exports = votedSchema;
```

If on the other hand, I don't use a subdoc, then it works just fine:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const OptionSchema = require('./Option');
const VotedSchema = require('./Voted');

const pollSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  options: [OptionSchema],
  dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  voted: {
    userID: [String],
    IPaddress: [String],
    MACaddress: [String]
  }
});

mongoose.model('polls', pollSchema);
```

Am I missing something super simple here? This problem has me a bit perplexed.

Comment: Can you clarify, what do you mean by not working in case of referenced sub document?

Answer (score 0):

This is not implemated in mongoose yet.

Check out this .

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/585

for now if you want , you can do the second option as you are doing .

or use

`VotedSchema.Type` or `VotedSchema.tree`

Embedding of document can be done by array .

vote: [VotedSchema]

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#single-embedded

Comment: Does that help ?